# Mobile browsers resize textareas when entering input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a rudimentary note-taking PWA, and my website (https://cloudwerewolf.github.io) works fine on desktop browsers and when launched from home screen on mobiles as a PWA, however when run in a mobile browser from navigating directly to the link, all textareas shrink when one of them is clicked on and I want the textareas to stay the same size as before instead of shrinking. Is it because of the keyboard skrinking the perceived width of the screen or is there another cause, and how can it be fixed?

EDIT: found & fixed the problem:

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    textarea {
        width: 43.5%;
    }
    #notehead {
        width: 20.5%;
    }
    #reH {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    textarea {
        width: 80%;
    }
    #notehead {
        width: 35%;
    }
}
```

When the keyboard appeared on my screen, CSS decided that the orientation was now landscape due to the viewport width now being less than the viewport height, and changed the sizes of the textareas and font sizes accordingly. I took out that chunk of code and replaced it with width percentages for the portrait mode placed into the regular textarea{} and #notehead{} CSS areas, with maximum widths in pixels to prevent the textareas from becoming too wide on desktops.

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS you are configuring your textarea to be `min-width: 80%`, so when the screen size is reduced the textarea will reduce until it reach the limit (80%) from here, the textarea won't reduce.

Try, maybe reducing the `min-width: 80%` to `min-width: 20%`

Please try to show your code in the question, we can help you to solve the problem in this manner not just putting a link to your website.

Comment: Taking that line out doesn't change the behavior, and why is the screen size being reduced?

Comment: Take a look in your website and go to developer console (pressing F12), search your textarea element and go to css properties: after this, change the `min-width: 80%` to `min-width: 20%`.

Comment: Hey @JJohnson, welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, my problem is that the textarea shrinks on a mobile browser when I don't want it to and I dont see how changing the minimum width would fix that.

Comment: Maybe you want to try specifying in your `media screen` adding property to `min-resolution` or `max resolution`, with this you will be attempting to extend the width of textarea when an user try to enter to your site from mobile browser.

Comment: When anyone set him mobile to landscape I see you are setting the width to 42.5%, try changing to 80% or another value depending on your preferences.